# Getting a translated country name from an address field

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, services

I have an address field from which I'm getting a country code and then, using the `address.country_repository` service, checking the country's name.

```
$full_country_list = \Drupal::service('address.country_repository')->getList();
$country_code = $user->field_nationality->first()->get("country_code")->getValue();
$result['nationality'] = t($full_country_list[$country_code], [], ['langcode'=>$user->get('langcode')->value]);
```

This repository returns a list with the country names translated in Drupal's default language (in my case, portuguese), but I'm trying to `t()`-function it to translate the string into other languages.

The `t()` function doesn't cut it, even if I pass the `langcode` option.

How can I get a translated version of the list so that I don't have to translate the string with `t()`?

Comment: getList() has a locale argument, try passing in your locale that you want to have it translated to. not sure if it's the same string as t() receives, the documentation mentions 'fr-FR' as example I think.

Answer (score 1):

The country name in the country list is already a translatable markup object. It's not possible to add new options to it. So your idea to translate the country name again, this time with a specific `langcode` in options, is right. But you have to get the untranslated string if you want to translate it again

```
t($full_country_list[$country_code]->getUntranslatedString(), [], ['langcode' => 'de'])
```

because how you do it you get the translated string when running the code in a non english language context and translating from a non english language is not supported.

---

Edit: this answer is valid for the core country list

```
$full_country_list = \Drupal::service('country_manager')->getList();
```

there are probably other versions in contrib, see comment from @Berdir.